# Track all local branches against remote

Tags: git, github, version-control

I did something fishy with my local repo a while back, which caused all my local branches to lose their remote tracking. I think I have my remote set up properly since I can see all remote branches and also add tracking to them.

When I create new branches locally it works fine.

This is the output of `git branch -llv`:

`$ git branch -lvv
  Branch 1                 d6c67c8 [origin/Branch 1] Commit message
  Branch 2                 17503c9 Commit message
  Branch 3                 4f987c4 Commit message
  Branch 4                 6e5670a [origin/Branch 4] Commit message
  Branch 5                 77bd14c Commit message`

**My question is wether I can add tracking between all my local `branch_x` and the remote equivalent `origin/branch_x` with one command?** Since I have a lot of branches it seems quite cumbersome to do it one by one. The remotes might very well be ahead of my local branch in many of the cases, but probably not the majority of the cases.

I was thinking of doing something like `git push -u origin --all`, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could advice is the following:

`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/your_branch`

sets it for one branch.

Now, you would have to write a bash script that would for each branch would do:

```
git checkout $your_branch
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/$your_branch
```

One other thing:

```
branches=()
eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"
for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
     echo $branch
done
```

Would print for you names of all the branches you have, prefixed by /refs/heads
You can use this in your script.

In fact your problem should be solved by running:

```
branches=()
eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"
for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
     branch_name=`echo $branch | "sed s|refs/heads/||"`
     git checkout $branch_name
     git branch --set-upstream-to origin/$branch_name
done
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! My bash-skills are really lacking, but it seems like there was a missing double quote (`"`) after the `sed` command. I edited your post to fix this. Feel free to reject it if I misunderstood something.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another form of the accepted answer, letting `git` strip the paths and dropping the bash array. Also, not attempting to track the `master` branch (as it's usually implicit) or `HEAD`. Replace the last line with `less` to preview the commands.

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='[[ %(refname) =~ /master$ ]] \
  || [[ %(refname) =~ /HEAD$ ]] \
  || git branch --track %(refname:lstrip=3) %(refname)' refs/remotes/origin |
    while read line; do eval "${line}"; done
```